# jQuery link is not working in WordPress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

This is my code.In browser you can see that all links are working properly but jQuery in absence their. I also tired this way (wp_enqueue_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js',array(),'1.9.1',true);) but same case happened. Actually I want to load jquery from wp includes folder.What can I do ?

[image: [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlO9M.png)

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script("themejs", $file_dir . "/js/themejs.js", false, "1.0");` use this code to emqueue the script

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load custom jquery, you should firstly remove default lib by

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

Then you can write

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js',array(),'1.9.1',true);
```